# How do you remove quotes from output?

Tags: yq

I don't see a corresponding option in `yq` to what `jq` has:

```
  -r               output raw strings, not JSON texts;
```

My exact usage is:

```
cat example.xml | yq --input-format xml --output-format  json
```

Comment: cat - | yq --input-format xml --output-format  text

Comment: Do you want JSON or TEXT output? If you want JSON output, then `-r` makes no sense (neither would it in jq). If you want TEXT output, then simply drop `--output-format json`

Comment: Do update which version of `yq` are you using. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info for the multiple versions that exist. Also update a sample input and an _expected_ output desired

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I'm trying to do 2 things in one. In fact my workaround of piping to jq is actually the right way to go if I need json as an intermediate analysis of the query I'm gradually trying to build up

Comment: Feel free to post as an answer so you can get full credit. Or I might have to,  so I can explain more cheaply where I've gone wrong in the premise of what I'm trying to do.